# How to upload this gridview of base 64 converted images to firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

This is the code I am working on, make a multiple selection of images and the most in a gridview array that calls it ImageList, but I would recommend converting the images to a base64 to have more efficiency when uploading and displaying the images, so I looked for examples and documentation and I found a way to convert them, but I was somewhat confused, because the array where the images are stored was ready List of images I had to pass it to a chain of chains, but I did not understand very well how to upload them to the firebase both the storage and the database, since they are images that will be saved of products that will be shown in the store this is the code

here is the activity where the data will be uploaded, the data as name price and description already uploaded to the database the imagenes not.

```
public class adminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nombreP, precioP, infoP;
    int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imagenUri;
    Button btnCargar;
    Button btnEditar;
    GridView gvImagenes;

    List<Uri> listaImagenes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Uri> listaBase64Imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
    GridViewAdapter baseAdapter;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    StorageReference mStorageRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

        /*INICIALIZAMOS LA CONEXION CON FIREBASE*/
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        nombreP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameProducto);
        precioP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.precioProducto);
        infoP =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.infoProducto);
        gvImagenes = findViewById(R.id.gvImagenes);
        btnEditar = findViewById(R.id.editar);
        btnCargar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cargar);

        btnEditar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                abrirGaleria();
            }
        });

        btnCargar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nombre = nombreP.getText().toString();
                String precio = precioP.getText().toString().trim();
                String infor = infoP.getText().toString();


                if (!nombre.isEmpty() && !precio.isEmpty() && !infor.isEmpty()){
                    cargarUsuario();
                    limpiarCaja();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(adminActivity.this,"Deben llenarse todos los campos.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void limpiarCaja() {
        nombreP.setText("");
        precioP.setText("");
        infoP.setText("");
    }

    public void cargarUsuario() {

        listaBase64Imagenes.clear();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < listaImagenes.size() ; i++){
            try {
                InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(listaImagenes.get(i));
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                String cadena = convertirUriToBase64(bitmap);

                enviarImagen(cadena);

                bitmap.recycle();
            } catch (IOException e){

            }
        }


        //Toast.makeText(this, "Producto Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String nombre = nombreP.getText().toString();
        String precio = precioP.getText().toString();
        String infor = infoP.getText().toString();

        productos p = new productos();
        p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        p.setNombre(nombre);
        p.setPrecio(precio);
        p.setInformacion(infor);
        databaseReference.child("Productos").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);
        Toast.makeText(adminActivity.this,"Agregado.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void enviarImagen(final String cadena) {
        StorageReference folderRef = mStorageRef.child("imagenesProductos");

        folderRef.putFile((Uri) listaImagenes).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();
            }
        });
    }

    private String convertirUriToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encode = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return encode;
    }

    private void abrirGaleria() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "SELECCIONA LAS IMAGENES"),PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            /*PARA UNA SOLA IMAGEN*/
            if (clipData == null){
                imagenUri = data.getData();
                listaImagenes.add(imagenUri);
            }
        }else {
            /*PARA VARIAS IMAGENES*/
            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
                listaImagenes.add(clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri());
            }
        }

        baseAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(adminActivity.this, listaImagenes);
        gvImagenes.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
    }

}
```

and here is the gridview adapter code

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listaImagenes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listaImagenes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null){
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_carga_imagenes, null);
        }

        ImageView ivImagen = view.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);
        ImageButton ibtnEliminar = view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnEliminar);

        ivImagen.setImageURI(listaImagenes.get(position));

        ibtnEliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listaImagenes.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

here i point out the method where i try to make the connection to the storage of firebase, they could help to rebuild it in order to be able to upload them to the storage and also to the database with their respective name, price and description

```
private void enviarImagen(final String cadena) {
        StorageReference folderRef = mStorageRef.child("imagenesProductos");

        folderRef.putFile((Uri) listaImagenes).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS in writing. It is hard to read, and is considered yelling.

Comment: sorry i made the change and take your recommendation how. are you? . can you help me with my problem

Comment: Thanks. There's still quite a bit of code, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what specific piece of it isn't doing what you expect it to do. Can you reduce the code to the [minimum that is required for any of us to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful) or at the very least point out what line isn't working for youj?

Comment: it is not so much a failure, if I have made myself understood like this. I will explain you. that activity is a product registration for a store. where the administrator can enter a product with its name, price, description and some images. not one, but several images. and converted them to base64. In the "cargarUsuario" (loadUser) method I am making the list run and the images that I find in that array equal it to a method to convert them and there I call it "convertUriToBase64".

Comment: In this method I convert the images that I put in the array, my question is. well, it is my first project in android studio using firebase as a database manager and my problem is that i don't know how to upload that array to the firebase storage. I followed the documentation that firebase gives me to be able to make the connection, but when doing the method it gives me an error. In the method called "enviarImagen"(sendImagen)

Comment: there I send the images to storage, I would like to know if they could help me complete this process so that they are stored in the storage. because I really didn't make it and I'm looking for help to make it happen.

Comment: Hey Juan. Thanks for that explanation. As you probably realized, this is quite a complete use-case, which is really hard to help with. Unless somebody happens to spot the problem by scanning your code, it is unlikely we'll be able to debug it in our minds by reading the question. That's why I asked which precise line/section of the code is not working for you, so that you can debug it and we can hopefully help with a more isolated problem.

Comment: Basically in the "enviarImagen" method line (sendImage) you would need to call what would be the list converted to base64 and send it to the firebase storage. It is my first project and uploading an image is easy. but uploading multiple images the difficulty is greater. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 250 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: The `while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());` loop you use looks suspect to me. I seldom see good results from doing such a so-called tight loop on Android. Also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62283284/209103) on how to property get the download URL from an image.

Comment: Hello Frank, @FrankvanPuffelen I am not supposed to have completed the sentence there. but that is the method that I call to send the image to the storage, I am sorry if I am somewhat confused, but it is my first project and I was stuck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still little bit of confusion, In my case what i understand from you, you want to store images to firebase in BASE64 format.

```
  String encode = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now, you don't have you store string, you can simply store byte[] in firbase and retrive it and just converted it to bitmap, here is a example for you:

```
 byte[] byteImage = Base64.decode(encode, Base64.DEFAULT);
 Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: Hi how are you my friend? . if i want to store base64 images to firebase storage. Are you sure i should not store the string? Because what I'm trying to save is not an image, but an array of images. sorry my question is confusing for all of you. I have a method called "convertUriToBase64" in that method I am converting my image array to base64. the array of images I am showing them in a gridview so I also published the gridview driver code.